# I can't run bundler, keep getting error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, bundler

I have just migrated my RoR dev environmnent over to Ubuntu. I pulled a project that I'm working on from github, and am attempting to install all of the necessary gems. However, whenever I run `bundle` or `bundle install` or `bundle install exec`  I get the following error:

```
    edu@edu:~/Workspace/SuitBrokers$ bundle install exec
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Installing rake (0.9.2.2) 
Installing multi_json (1.0.3) 
Installing activesupport (3.1.0) 
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions 
Installing builder (3.0.0) 
Installing i18n (0.6.0) 
Installing activemodel (3.1.0) 
Installing erubis (2.7.0) 
Installing rack (1.3.5) 
Installing rack-cache (1.0.3) 
Installing rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Installing rack-test (0.6.1) 
Installing hike (1.2.1) 
Installing tilt (1.3.3) 
Installing sprockets (2.0.3) 
Installing actionpack (3.1.0) 
Installing mime-types (1.17.2) 
Installing polyglot (0.3.3) 
Installing treetop (1.4.10) 
Installing mail (2.3.0) 
Installing actionmailer (3.1.0) 
Installing arel (2.2.1) 
Installing tzinfo (0.3.31) 
Installing activerecord (3.1.0) 
Installing activeresource (3.1.0) 
Installing ansi (1.4.1) 
Using bundler (1.0.21) 
Installing cocaine (0.2.0) 
Installing coffee-script-source (1.1.3) 
Installing execjs (1.2.9) 
Installing coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Installing json (1.6.1) with native extensions 
Installing rdoc (3.11) 
Installing thor (0.14.6) 
Installing railties (3.1.0) 
Installing coffee-rails (3.1.1) 
Installing jquery-rails (1.0.18) 
Installing mysql (2.8.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/edu/Workspace/SuitBrokers/exec/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/edu/Workspace/SuitBrokers/exec/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing mysql (2.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql -v '2.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Has anyone dealt with this particular pain? Your help is eternally appreciated.

Comment: could you include the output of `cat /home/edu/Workspace/SuitBrokers/exec/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out`?

Comment: that file says verbatim what the ouput says starting after this line "Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Comment: however, I don't see extconf.rb anywhere in the directory ruby.../bin/ruby

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to tell bundler where to find the mysql-dev stuff on your box.  Usually something like the following will work:

```
bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Of course, you'll need to replace the path above with your actual path to mysql_config.  If you don't have mysql_config installed then you will need the mysql-dev package installed on your server.  It looks like you're probably on a shared server, so hopefully the development package is already installed.  If not, you'll need to request it.

Comment: thanks @JasonK. How do I figure out if I have the mysql-dev package installed?  Where do i look for it? is there a command to run?  I am using Ubuntu 11.10 which is installed in a Oracle Virtual machine running in Windows 7.

Comment: I believe on Ubuntu the package is called libmysqlclient-dev.  So the command to install it would be something like `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 4):

The library you're missing, on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) is: *libmysqlclient-dev*.
The line below did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```