# How to install mySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, installation

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to back-end (especially Ruby), and I'm completely lost.

What I'm supposed to do is use a couple of commands to get a project on localhost. By the way, it's ruby backed.

I've been told to install rvm (which I've done several times already), and then use rvm to install ruby 2.0.0.

Now, I have to run

```
bundle install
```

and then,

```
bundle exec rackup
```

So, when I run `bundle install`, it says

```
An error occurred while installing mysql (2.8.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.

Make sure that `gem install mysql -v '2.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Can someone please help me? I'm so lost! If you need more information, here you go:

- The project has tons of .rb files along with the index.html and it's respective css files
- I've installed bundler
- I've changed the directory to the project folder (all commands were done under that directory)
- Any more information that you need? Let me know!

Comment: I believe you want to actually use the [`mysql2`](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) gem. The `mysql` gem hasn't been updated in over a year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't run bundler, keep getting error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134113/i-cant-run-bundler-keep-getting-error)

Comment: Is mysql (the database, not the gem) itself installed? If not, which OS are you on?

Comment: Sorry, where do I install mySQL? (told you, I'm a complete newbie)

Comment: @p11y I've installed it, now what?

Comment: Try this command on your terminal:`gem install mysql -v '2.8.1'`

Comment: You can install mysql for example with the homebrew package manager. Pay close attention to the output, it will show you the commands to start mysql and/or have it start automatically on boot. Then, try to bundle install again.

Comment: @p11y I installed mysql with homebrew and started mysql but it's still not working. When I do gem install mysql it comes up with 'ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/extensions/universal-darwin-10/1.8/mysql-2.8.1'

Comment: Do you use a ruby manager like rvm or rbenv? If so, your shell is not properly set up and you should check whether it picks up the right ruby version with `ruby -v`. Otherwise, you are using your default system ruby and you should prefix gem install commands with `sudo` to give Rubygems permission to write to system folders. RVM and Rbenv will install in other locations, where sudo rights are not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

please use below link to download mysql for particular OS and install it
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html

Comment: Thanks, but after that, what should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134113/i-cant-run-bundler-keep-getting-error?lq=1

Comment: try above link, it may help you

Comment: It's working now! I had a few problems with the gems, but I deleted them and started from scratch. Thanks for your help!